# Matlab/Simulink LookupTable with Workspace vectors

Tags: matlab, simulink, lookup-tables

I am new with Simulink and I am struggling with the Dynamic Lookup Table (inputs : x, xadta, ydata; output: y).

I have several 2D vectors (xdata and ydata) stored in my Workspace and I would like to use them in Simulink in a Dynamic Lookup Table to return a value (y) depending on another variable in Simulink (x). 
If I understand how it works I have first to convert my 2D vectors in structures (time,values,dimensions) to be read in Simulink ?
So I did it this way but I got an error :

```
    vector.time = xdata; % dimension 1x100
    vector.signals.values = ydata; % dimension 1x100
    vector.signals.dimensions = [1 100];
    save('vector.mat','vector')
```

**Error**

*"The last dimension of each
'signals.values' field must be the same as the number of rows in the 'time' field."*

Besides I am not sure that what I am trying to do is appropriate... I use the xdata of my vectors/structures as "time" in the structures to get my vectors readable in Simulink. But I do not think it should have anything to do with time notion. I just want the Dynamic Lookup Table to return the "ydata" value of the vector/structure corresponding to the value of "x"="xdata". Only "x" change with time in the Simulation.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you should just be using the `1D Lookup Table`, with your `xdata` and `ydata` variables (defined in your MATLAB Workspace) used as the block parameters.

As to the error you're getting, it seems to be related to using the `From File` block (which it looks like you're using to get data into your model) not the look-up table itself.  To get that to work, define your time vector as a column vector, not a row vector as you've done, and think of each row as a different time point.

At each time point, you'll get a different signal value.  This is like a look-up table itself (looking up the signal value for each different time value), but doesn't sound like what you are really wanting to achieve.